# Trying to make a a single line sink a boat in java

Tags: java

Ok, I'm trying to make a simple sink a boat game in java, but am running into a java.lang.numberformatexception and don't know what I'm doing wrong... Here's the actual code I'm using. Sorry very noob still.

It's a simple 7 tiles battlefield with a ship on 3 tiles.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class New4
{
int randnum;
static char[] field;
int numofhits;
String userinput;
private static Scanner userguess;
public static void main(String[] args)
{

new New4();


}   

public New4()
{
String input = "";
int numofhits = 0;
int randnum = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
char[] field = new char[7];
for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    field[i] = '*';
}
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
{
    field[randnum] = 'O';
    randnum++;
}
for(char c : field)
{
    System.out.print("|" + c);

}
System.out.print("|");
while(numofhits < 3)
{
AskUser();
input = userinput;
if(field[Integer.parseInt(input)] == 'O'){System.out.println("A terrifc hit");numofhits++;}
else{System.out.println("A blasted miss");}
System.out.println("Great game");}

}
public String AskUser()
{

String userinput;
System.out.println("Guess a number: ");
userguess = new Scanner(System.in);
userinput = userguess.next();

return userinput;

}

}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. Only thing is that you declare variables twice. `int numofhits ,int randnum, char[] field` etc and then again in the constructor. And you can remove `String userinput;` from the `askUser()` function.

Comment: Thanks, working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = askUser(); //instead of userinput = input;
```